# Any way to create zram disk (not swap) during boot time except via script?

Tags: boot, kernel-modules, zram

https://askubuntu.com/questions/130374/ramdisk-compressed-writeable-no-swap

Gives script to make zram disk (load module, set parameter, format block device, mount). Is there any way to have same result via `/etc/fstab`? I guess if not best way to run the script is via `Systemd` (system is Linux Mint)? TIA

Edited part of the script:

```
modprobe zram num_devices=1 
echo 256M > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mke2fs -q -m 0 -b 4096 -O sparse_super -L zram /dev/zram0
mount -o discard /dev/zram0 /mount_point
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make things seem a little tidier by putting the script into a mount
[external helper](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/mount.8.html#external%20helpers).
For example, an fstab entry of

```
/dev/zram0 /mount_point myzram x-systemd.automount,discard
```

should cause systemd to run the command

```
/sbin/mount.myzram /dev/zram0 /mount_point -o discard
```

You need to create the file `/sbin/mount.myzram`, make it executable, and put the script in there:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
zramname=$(basename "$1")
modprobe zram num_devices=1
echo 256M >/sys/block/"$zramname"/disksize || exit
mke2fs -q -m 0 -b 4096 -O sparse_super -L zram /dev/"$zramname" || exit
mount "$@"
```

You may need to extend the PATH so that modprobe and mke2fs are found, or
you can use their full pathnames.

Comment: Hi, finally got my hands to try. Thanks for the tip. It works, but I was surprised invoking `mount` that way adds certain tweaks: 1) `nosuid, nodev,noexec` get added to options - that I could counter with explicit `exec` 2) even with explicit `user` option `umount` is not permitted for ordinary user, whereas when script was run via systemd units it later works even w/out `user` option (I guess due to `udisks` and zram being block device). I'm not sure yet if (2)  is desirable result or not. Do you know why is there such difference? TIA

Comment: Above was for `mount /mount_point` after edit of `fstab`, now after reboot system took tines longer to load desktop after login, zramdisk device is visible but gives error `no such device` in GUI and in `findmnt` output options are some `proto`, `pipe` and also `relatime` whereas in the script option is specifically `noatime`, `ls mount point` hang. I'm disappointed, in theory your tip was indeed tidier.

Comment: Running script via systemd wanted-by target results in working zram disk. In Nemo device is called "...Volume", not zramdisk but that is the only issue I see for that way.

Comment: I've only done some simple tests with the mount helper, but I'm disappointed that that it failed to cope with your more complex requirement. Often it depends on the version of systemd and other software. `man systemd-fstab-generator` and `man systemd-mount` might provide some other clues, but I would stay with whatever works "well enough".